# maya and its VRML export with artoolkit

Tags: maya, artoolkit, vrml

I am currently working on a project using Artoolkit ( C and C++ language software library that lets programmers easily develop Augmented Reality applications ) and Maya2013. I wonder if anyone, by any chance, has successfully exported VRML files from maya and display it in artoolkit.
The wrl files can be viewed inside cosmoplayer, but they just don't work well with artoolkit.

[1]
Well, if I simply write

```
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
    material Material { }
}
geometry Box { }
```

}

It works well with artoolkit.

[2]
When I export the model (ie, a sphere), it just doesn't work. Here's the wrl file of it.

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8 CosmoWorlds V1.0
WorldInfo
{
 title  "hydrant"
 info   "VRML2.0 created with Version 1.3, from Alias Maya 2013"
}
NavigationInfo
{
 type [ "EXAMINE" ]
 headlight  TRUE
 speed      1.000000
}
Switch
{
 whichChoice    -1
 choice
 [
  Shape
  {
   appearance Appearance
   {
    material DEF lambert1_0 Material
    {
     diffuseColor   0.400000 0.400000 0.400000
     specularColor  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
     emissiveColor  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
     shininess      0.000000
     transparency   0.000000
    }
   }
  }
  Shape
  {
   geometry DEF pCube1_0Geo IndexedFaceSet
   {
    convex FALSE
    solid FALSE
    coord DEF pCube1GeoPoints Coordinate
    {
     point [
      -1.254 -1.013 2.585,
      1.254 -1.013 2.585,
      -1.254 1.013 2.585,
      1.254 1.013 2.585,
      -1.254 1.013 -2.585,
      1.254 1.013 -2.585,
      -1.254 -1.013 -2.585,
      1.254 -1.013 -2.585
     ]
    }
    coordIndex [
     0 1 3 2 -1, 
     2 3 5 4 -1, 
     4 5 7 6 -1, 
     6 7 1 0 -1, 
     1 7 5 3 -1, 
     6 0 2 4 -1
    ]
    normalPerVertex TRUE
    normal Normal
    {
     vector [
      0.000 0.000 1.000,
      0.000 0.000 1.000,
      0.000 0.000 1.000,
      0.000 0.000 1.000,
      0.000 1.000 0.000,
      0.000 1.000 0.000,
      0.000 1.000 0.000,
      0.000 1.000 0.000,
      0.000 0.000 -1.000,
      0.000 0.000 -1.000,
      0.000 0.000 -1.000,
      0.000 0.000 -1.000,
      0.000 -1.000 0.000,
      0.000 -1.000 0.000,
      0.000 -1.000 0.000,
      0.000 -1.000 0.000,
      1.000 0.000 0.000,
      1.000 0.000 0.000,
      1.000 0.000 0.000,
      1.000 0.000 0.000,
      -1.000 0.000 0.000,
      -1.000 0.000 0.000,
      -1.000 0.000 0.000,
      -1.000 0.000 0.000
     ]
    }
    normalIndex [
     0 1 2 3 -1,
     4 5 6 7 -1,
     8 9 10 11 -1,
     12 13 14 15 -1,
     16 17 18 19 -1,
     20 21 22 23 -1
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
Group
{
 children
 [
  DEF persp Viewpoint
  {
   position -6.664414 5.734681 17.361393
   orientation  -0.626571 -0.770664 -0.116128 0.472021
   fieldOfView  0.950022
   description  "persp"
  }
  DEF pCube1 Transform
  {
   translation      0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
   rotation     0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
   scale        1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
   scaleOrientation 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
   children Shape
   {
    appearance Appearance
    {
     material USE lambert1_0
    }
    geometry USE pCube1_0Geo
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

[3]
Here's the version of .wrl file which works in artoolkit

```
    #VRML V2.0 utf8

Background {                  #remove these lines
 skyColor .7 .7 1             #
 }                            # when placing this
 Viewpoint {                  #
  position 0 0 7            # object in a VRML world
   }                          #
NavigationInfo {              # or apartment.
 type "EXAMINE"               #
 }                            #

WorldInfo {
   title "Animated Snowman"
    info [ "Copyright 1988 modeled by Kiwano [Andrew Reitemeyer] kiwano@t-online.de "
          "This model is linkware. Non commercial users are required to link to" 
                    " http://home.t-online.de/home/kiwano4 "
                    "Commercial users must pay a small fee, details and more models from the above url"
          "This node must remain unaltered in this code"
          ]
          }    



 Transform {           # main grouping node
translation 0 0 0      # controls position
scale 1 1 1            # controls size
rotation 0 0 0 0       # controls orientation
  children [



DEF Bottom Transform {
translation 0 -1 0
  scale 1.2 1 1.2
    children [
    DEF Ball  Shape {
        appearance Appearance {
          material Material {
           diffuseColor 1 1 1
           specularColor .9 .9 1
           shininess 1
           ambientIntensity .2
          # transparency .2
           }
         }  
       geometry Sphere {
         radius 1
         }
       }
       DEF  See VisibilitySensor {}
     ]
   }     
DEF Middle Transform {
 translation 0 0 0
  scale .9 .9 .9
    children [
    USE Ball  
     ]
   }     
DEF head Transform {
 translation 0 .9 0
  scale .6 .6 .6
    children [
    USE Ball  
     ]
   }  
DEF Eye1 Transform {
    translation .35 1.1 .4
    children [
    DEF Eye  Shape {
        appearance Appearance {
          material Material {
           diffuseColor 0 0 0
           specularColor 1 1 1
           shininess 1
           ambientIntensity 1
           }
         }  
       geometry Sphere {
         radius .1
         }
       }
     ]
   }     
DEF Eye2 Transform {
    translation -.35 1.1 .4
    children [
    USE Eye 
     ]
   }  
DEF Nose  Transform {
    translation 0 .9 .8
    rotation 1 0 0 1.57
    children [
     Shape {
        appearance Appearance {
          material Material {
           diffuseColor .8 .5 0
           specularColor .9 .6 0
           shininess .3
           ambientIntensity .2
           }
         }  
       geometry Cone {
         bottomRadius .1
         height .5
         }
       }
     ]
   }     
DEF Hat Transform  {
 translation 0 0 0
   children [

Transform {
    translation 0 1.3 0
    rotation 0 1 1 -.1
    children [
      Shape {
        appearance DEF Felt Appearance {
          material Material {
           diffuseColor 0 0 0
           specularColor 1 1 1
           shininess 1
           ambientIntensity 1
           }
         }  
       geometry Cylinder {
         radius .7
         height .05
         }
       }
     ]
   }  
 Transform {
    translation 0 1.6 0
    rotation 0 1 1 -.1
    children [
      Shape {
        appearance USE Felt 
       geometry Cylinder {
         radius .5
         height .6
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
 }# end Hat   
DEF Arm1  Transform {
    children [
    DEF Arm  Shape {
        appearance DEF Stick Appearance {
          material Material {
           diffuseColor .7 .6 .4
           specularColor 1 1 0
           shininess .2
           ambientIntensity .1
           }
         }  
      geometry Extrusion {
        creaseAngle 1.4
         crossSection [ .1 0, 
                     .071 -.07,  0 -.1
                      -.07 -.071,  -.1 0,
                      -.071 .07,  0 .1         #18
                      .07 .071,  .1 0,
          ]
         spine [.6 .35 0, 1.5 .2 0, 2 0 .5 ]
         scale [ 1 1, .7 .7, .5 .5]

       }
     }
     ]
   }

 DEF Arm2  Transform {
    children [
    Shape {
        appearance USE Stick 
      geometry DEF Tipper Extrusion {
        creaseAngle 1.4
         crossSection [ .1 0, 
                     .071 -.07,  0 -.1
                      -.07 -.071,  -.1 0,
                      -.071 .07,  0 .1         #18
                      .07 .071,  .1 0,
          ]
         spine [-.6 .35 0, -1.5 .2 0, -2 0 .5]
        # spine [-.6 .35 0, -1.5 .8 0, -.65 1.4 0 ]
         scale [ 1 1, .7 .7, .5 .5]

       }
     }
     ]
   }


  ]
 }  

DEF Tick TimeSensor {
   cycleInterval 15
   loop TRUE 
   enabled FALSE
   }


DEF Lift CoordinateInterpolator {
     key [0, .35, .45, .5, .65, .75, 1]
     keyValue [-.6 .35 0, -1.5 .2 0, -2 0 .5,

               -.6 .35 0, -1.5 .2 0, -2 0 .5, 

               -.6 .35 0, -1.5 .8 0, -.65 1.4 0

               -.6 .35 0, -1.5 1 0, -1.4 1.9 0

               -.6 .35 0, -1.5 .8 0, -.65 1.4 0 

                -.6 .35 0, -1.5 .2 0, -2 0 .5, 

               -.6 .35 0, -1.5 .2 0, -2 0 .5,                

               ]
            } 

DEF Doff PositionInterpolator {
     key [0, .45, .5, .65, 1] 
     keyValue [ 0 0 0, 0 0 0, -.6 .5 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 0 ]
     }

ROUTE See.isActive TO Tick.set_enabled                 
ROUTE Tick.fraction_changed TO Lift.set_fraction
ROUTE Lift.value_changed TO Tipper.set_spine 
ROUTE Tick.fraction_changed TO Doff.set_fraction
ROUTE Doff.value_changed TO Hat.set_translation  

WorldInfo {
   title "Arcadia"
   info [ "(C)1997 modeled by Kiwano (Andrew Reitemeyer) kiwano@t-online.de"]

          }
```

I can't tell the difference between the code in part[2] and that in part[3]. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one is a fire hydrant, the other is a dancing snowman,that's the main difference ;)

In [2] the switch node's "whichChoice" is -1, which makes it show nothing.  Try changing it to 0 to show the first child.  Or eliminate it, I don't think you need it.